# iOS: How do I detect if an email has been successfully sent?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to check if an Email message was sent and display an Alert allowing the user know.
I tried the delegate method below , but sadly will display the alert message if user cancels as well. Any help will be appreciated and rewarded.

```
 - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error{
if (error) { UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %@", [error description]] delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}


     NSLog(@"email sent");
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to look at the `result`. The `error` parameter should only be looked at after consulting the `result` value first.

Comment: BTW - The `result` will be `MFMailComposeResultSent` even if the email is stuck in the outbox due to some issue. There is no way to know if the email was truly sent out or not.

Comment: What i have seen most people do is to create a separate database that would verify whether or not mail has been sent out by logging all mails that would be sent and then having the web server send out the mail. But this sort of system would vary from case to case though. It would also depend on who would be using your app, i.e whether it be for the general public or for use by your corp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that it means when that function is called is that *something* happened with the email because the `MFMailComposeViewController` is finished. To know what did actually happen, you have to take a look at the value of `result`, which can be any of the following:

```
MFMailComposeResultCancelled
MFMailComposeResultSaved
MFMailComposeResultSent
MFMailComposeResultFailed
```

As rmaddy says in comments, you can't be 100% sure that the email was actually sent (it could be stuck in the outbox). What `MFMailComposeResultSent` signifies, then, is that the email has been sent over to the Mail app, which will send it as soon as it can.

Comment: Are you able to check if the send button was at least pushed?

Comment: @TwoFace It doesn't work like that. The method is `-didFinishWithResult`. The `MFMailComposeViewController` finished, and one of the above results happened with the email. If there's a hack way to find out if the button was pushed I'm not aware of it, but it's not going to be in this function--by the time this function is called the button has already either been pressed or not pressed.

Comment: You get MFMailComposeResultSent iff "Send" is pressed.
You get MFMailComposeResultSaved iff "Save Draft" is pressed.
You get MFMailComposeResultCancelled iff "Delete Draft" is pressed.
These result values are directly related to the user actions on the compose sheet. None guarantee what actually happens with the mail. The mail app is a separate sandbox.